# Use ZeroMQ in ROS with Package zeromq_catkin - How to include?

Tags: cmake, zeromq, ros, failed-installation, catkin

I am trying to setup a ROS-Node to communicate with other OS via ZeroMQ ( no choice here ).

I use **ROS Kinetic Kame** on **ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and *catkin build* (instead of *catkin_make*).

Luckily, there already is a Catkin-Package (a Wrapper) for ZeroMQ available, which builds just perfectly for me: https://github.com/ethz-asl/zeromq_catkin

But when I try to include the Cpp-Wrapper `#include "zmq.hpp"`, which is also installed with the above package, the compiler cannot find the header file.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Every hint is highly appreciated.

---

**Additional Infos**

My **`package.xml`** (for my own Node) has in it:

```
<build_depend>zeromq_catkin</build_depend>
<run_depend>zeromq_catkin</run_depend>
```

My **`CMakeLists.txt`** has in it:

```
find_package(zeromq_catkin REQUIRED)
include_directories(
    ${zeromq_catkin_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
target_link_libraries(my_node
    ${zeromq_catkin_LIBRARY}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Small but important mistake, I typed <kbd>`INCLUDE_DIR`</kbd> but there was a <kbd>**`S`**</kbd> missing, it should be <kbd>**`INCLUDE_DIRS`**</kbd> in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(
    ${zeromq_catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```